# Spectrum colour picker post id and colour to php

Tags: php, javascript, post, colors, spectrum

I am using the JavaScript Spectrum Colour Picker. I need to post the #myid to colour.php within the function(color). Thanks in advance.

```
<script>

$("#myid").spectrum({

preferredFormat: "hex6",

    change: function(color) {

    $.post('colour.php', { colour: color.toHex } );

}
});

</script>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. You should definitively try to narrow down your problem: is this a JavaScript issue or a database issue? What are you trying to do: store a color? Retrieve the *exact* color "ID"? Return the ID of the *closest* color? In addition, and in order to obtain more meaningful answers, I suggest you to provide a *concrete* [SSCC example](http://sscce.org/) and to precise the expected result (what should be "returned?" what should be "in the DB?")

Comment: Cheers Sylvain, I have made edits to my post which hopefully make it more succinct.

Comment: @RustyBadRobot So your question is about sending a POST query with the chosen color when a color gets selected? This is related to the usage of your JQuery plugin, not to MySQL, right?

Comment: @RandomSeed You are absolutely right, I have changed my title to reflect this (this is my first question and i'm learning). I need to POST colour and id (#myid) to colour.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('colour.php', { colour: color.toHex, id: (this.id) } );
```

I answered my own question this morning, this now posts the colour and id over to php. Thanks to @RandomSeed for making me think about what I was actually trying to achieve!